# Oracle Hyperion MDM Web Service API and .NET interop

Tags: java, web-services, hyperion, master-data-management

We have Oracle Hyperion Master Data Management (aka Data Relationship Management) installed along with it's Web Service API, which is essentially an EAR file deployed on WebLogic. A built-in server side security policy has been attached to this web service. We have a .NET client which needs to speak to this Web Service endpoint, but we are not really sure how to set the client side security policy as defined by Oracle.

Versions used - DRM: 11.1.2.1; WebLogic: 10.3.4

I'm looking for pointers (& sample code if possible) on how we can achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for this from http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e16098.pdf. Section 5 in that document speaks of how to export the certificate from WLS and import the same into the .NET client app along w/ other config as specified in the document. Hope this helps.